# Add Event on Google calendar with .NET - c#

Tags: .net

I'm trying to add an event with google calendar API, this is the code that I'm using:

```
public void InsertEntry()
{
    EventEntry entry = new EventEntry();

    entry.Title.Text = "Test";
    entry.Content.Content = "Content Test";

    Where location = new Where();
    location.ValueString = "Location";
    entry.Locations.Add(location);

    When time = new When(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddDays(2));
    entry.Times.Add(time);

    Uri calendarUri = new Uri("https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/CALENDER_ID/public/basic");

    AtomEntry insertedEntry = service.Insert(calendarUri,entry);
}
```

I'm getting this error:
*"Additional information: Execution of authentication request returned unexpected result: 404"*

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=5101

Comment: I've seen this  , so I should use p12 Key?

Comment: @CodeCaster . do you know to to use this: ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail) //create credential using certigicate
            {
                Scopes = new[] { "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/" } //this scopr is for spreadsheets, check google scope FAQ for others
            }.FromCertificate(certificate)); 
 but for calendar and not spreadsheet?

Comment: It says right there _"this scope is for spreadsheets, check google scope FAQ for others"_... This is the FAQ: https://developers.google.com/gdata/faq and this is Calendar's scope: `http(s)://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/`.

Comment: Eventually I solve this with :http://www.daimto.com/google-calendar-api-authentication-with-c/, I did authentication using p12 key.